# Внести рандом номер в таблицу

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос обновления таблицы и внесение раздомного номера:

```
UPDATE `user1` SET 
`u1_01_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.287') + '0.001', 
`u1_02_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.009') + '0.001', 
`u1_03_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001',
`u1_04_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001',
`u1_05_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_06_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001',
`u1_07_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '1.356') + '0.001',
`u1_08_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '2.356') + '0.001',
`u1_09_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '4.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_10_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '9.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_11_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_12_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_13_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001',
`u1_14_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001',
`u1_15_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '12.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_16_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '3.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_17_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '5.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_18_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '8.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_19_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_20_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '18.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_21_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '1.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_22_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '2.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_23_00`= FLOOR(RAND() * '3.356') + '0.001', 
`u1_23_59`= FLOOR(RAND() * '0.356') + '0.001' 
where `user1_date`=current_date and `user_id` = '1';
```

Но рандом не совсем рандомный получается.
Порактически всегда принимает значения минимальные, но и больше значения повторяют структуру.
Где кроется ошибка?

[image]

Если взглянуть на таблицу, то что уже внесено. Можно заметить, что внесена практически МИНИМАЛЬНАЯ единица, в то время как максимум 0.287 и минимум 0.001 - во всех 10-ти случаях внесено 0.001, а что-либо иное (к примеру, 0.057 или 0.009 или 0.156).
Если вносятся максимальные числа, которые больше, то после запятой все равно .001.
В этом проблема. Не сосвсем достоверный рандом между двумя числами получается.

Comment: @Mc Doc, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Добавил в первый пост, то в чем сомнение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из каких соображений выбрано 0.356 и 0.001? Вообще любая подобная пара - 18.356 / 0.001?

Если читать рук-во, то видно, что:
1) формула рандомизации у вас неверно записана

```
FLOOR (RAND * k) + l
```

а надо

```
FLOOR(l + RAND() * (k – l))
```

Тогда мы будем получать случайное R, которое лежит между l и k;

2) k и l - это integer, то есть целые числа. Если вам нужен decimal - получите достоверное случайное целое, а потом делите его на 1000.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.
Верно, формула рандома была неверная.

Для проверки я использовал:
{".
.
`u1_01_00`= FLOOR('1' + RAND() * ('100' - '1')), 
.
."}

Внеслось 69, 88 и так далее. Отлично.
После вписал в это выражение разделить на 1000:

{"...
`u1_01_00`= FLOOR(('1' + RAND() * ('100' - '1'))/'1000'), 
..."}

На 100% должно занестись 0,***
Новносится НОЛЬ.

Comment: Отвечаю на свой же вопрос.
Неверно написано выражение.

Верный ответ:

    "... u1_01_00= FLOOR('1' + RAND() * ('100' - '1')) / '1000', ..."

Comment: надо делить на 1000 результат от FLOOR:


FLOOR((1 + RAND() * 99))/1000